# How to find the location where data source has been saved in Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

How to find the location where data source has been saved in Spotfire ?

When I am in the Information Designer and I go to Data sources I can pick any, but how to check where was it saved ?

Comment: are you talking about the path of a data table? are you asking how to manually check it or if there is a way to check it via Python?

Comment: I am asking about the object called in Sp:"Data source" and specifically about, how to check where is it located in library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I have just located this option which is infact an answer to my question.